# Can I find documents based on duplicated fields?

Tags: solr, lucene, facet

I have a Solr server with data under this format:

```
{
  id: 1,
  text_1: "some_text1",
  text_2: "some_text2",
},
{
  id: 2,
  text_1: "some_text1",
  text_2: "some_text2",
}
```

I need to find documents like the ones I wrote above. Documents that have the same "text_1" and "text_2" values but different ids.

I've tried using facets, but I'm not sure if it helps. Firstly, it only returns a count of the duplicates and I need the id's of these documents. Secondly, I'm not sure that faceting over multiple fields does what I want. I'm not sure that:
`facet.field=text_1&facet.field=text_2` shows me a count of documents that have both those fields.

Thank you, I don't know much about Solr. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think facets are your best bet to get this done, but as you noticed you will need to issue at least two queries: one to get the facets and another to fetch the actual documents that belong to the facet (i.e. the duplicates in your case)

To get the multi facets to work for what you are trying to do you'll need to use PivotFaceting (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/faceting.html#pivot-decision-tree-faceting). The syntax is `facet=on&facet.pivot=field1,field2`

Make sure the field that you use for facets is a `string` field and not a `text` field.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll test it out.